# reversing an Integer with a special case

Tags: java, math

i am trying to reverse an integer but there is a condition. If the integer a does not fit in 32 bit signed integer value then the function should return 0. I am handling that case but the program raises an exception. Why ?

```
public class Solution {
    public  int reverse(int a) {
        String s = Integer.toString(a);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        if(s.charAt(0) == '-')
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        String n = sb.reverse().toString();
        int N = 0 -Integer.parseInt(n);
        if(N >= -2147483648 && N <= 2147483647)
            return N;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the above code.

Comment: what and where is your exception?

Comment: What do you think `Integer.parseInt()` should do when you pass it an integer that doesn't fit?

Comment: try `Long.parseLong()` instead. `Integer.parseInt()` can't parse anything bigger than an `Integer`

Comment: @Pshemo won't happen, since the input is `int`. The reverse always has the same number of digits as the original, thus it'll always be in `long` range

Comment: why are you removing the negative if there is one? wouldn't this mean you're always getting a negative value since you're doing `0 - alwaysApositiveNumber`?  Rather, shouldn't you be keeping track of the fact that you're removing the negative?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I misread your previous comment. I removed my comment already.

Comment: I think you must assign the string to a long. Then check if that long fits well within the integer range,if yes, assign it to an int. Else return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public  int reverse(int a) {
    boolean negative = a < 0;
    String s = Integer.toString(a);
    StringBuilder sb = negative ? new StringBuilder(s.substring(1)) 
                                  : new StringBuilder(s); 
    long reversed = Long.parseLong(sb.reverse().toString());
    reversed = negative ? 0L - reversed : reversed;
    if(reversed < MIN_VALUE || reversed > MAX_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Long.valueOf(reversed).intValue();
}
```